# Как скопировать данные из tableWidget в tableWidget_1?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator

Добрый день, создал программу которая забирает данные из БД и выводит их в qtableWidget_1 в котором выведенные строки можно отметить с помощью Check Box. Рядом есть qtablewidget_2 куда отмеченные строки нужно скопировать, подскажите как такое можно реализовать ?
Сам код вывода запроса из БД.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(5); // Указываем число колонок
ui->tableWidget->setShowGrid(true); // Включаем сетку
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection); // Разрешаем выделение только одного элемента
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);// Разрешаем выделение построчно
//ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);// Устанавливаем заголовки колонок
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(false);// Растягиваем последнюю колонку на всё доступное пространство
// ui->tableWidget->hideColumn(0);// Скрываем колонку под номером 0
  ui->tableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);//Запрещаем редактировать данные в полях таблицы
// Создаём запрос для для выборки записей из базы данных


QSqlQuery query = QSqlQuery(db);
if (!query.exec("SELECT * FROM mytable"))
{
   QMessageBox::information(this,"Окно информации","Не удалось выполнить запрос возможно нет соеденеия с базой данных.");
   qDebug() << query.lastError().databaseText();
   qDebug() << query.lastError().driverText();
   return;

}else{

/* Выполняем заполнение QTableWidget записями с помощью цикла
 * */
for(int i = 0; query.next(); i++){

    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(i);// Вставляем строку

    /* Устанавливаем в первую колонку id забирая его из результата SQL-запроса
     * Эта колонка будет скрыта
     * */
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()));


    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();// Создаём элемент, который будет выполнять роль чекбокса
    item->data(Qt::CheckStateRole);

    /* Проверяем, на статус нечетности, если нечетное устройство, то
     * выставляем состояние чекбокса в Checked, иначе в Unchecked
     * */
    if(query.value(1).toInt() == 1){
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    } else {
        item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    }

    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0, item);// Устанавливаем чекбокс во вторую колонку

    // Забираем все данные из результата запроса и устанавливаем в остальные поля
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,1, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,2, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(2).toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,3, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(3).toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,4, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(4).toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,5, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(5).toString()));


}

ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
db.close();
    }

  }
```

Comment: Читайте про паттерн MVC, который используется в Qt. В общем случае, вам нужно реализовать модель для вашего вью, унаследовав ее от QAbstractTableModel и создать класс, который будет представлять item в вашей модели.

Comment: @awesome  мне просто нужно скопировать из одного в другое

Comment: Выберите нужные item`ы и qtablewidget_2->setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem * item);

Comment: @awesome не подскажет почему так выдаёт ошибку ui->tableWidget_2->setItem(int 2, int 2, QTableWidgetItem * item);

Comment: void setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem * item) это сигнатура метода. В параметрах нужно передавать, то что указано в сигнатуре, то есть две переменных типа int и одну переменную типа указатель на QTableWidgetItem. Все таки придется почитать учебник, а не пытаться накидать на форму компонентов, не понимая вообще, что происходит и ждать, что это заработает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача решена:

```
ui->tableWidget_1->setItem(i,1, new QTableWidgetItem(ui->tableWidget->item(i, 1)->text()));
```

как вариант можно использовать так же данную конструкцию

```
ui->tableWidget_1->setItem(i,1, ui->tableWidget->item(i, 1)->clone());
```

Comment: А не пробовали так `ui->tableWidget_1->setItem(i,1, ui->tableWidget->item(i, 1)->clone());`?

Comment: @gil9red если только как вариант так как работает он так же.

Comment: Тогда лучше обновить ответ, добавив это решение ;)